# Table entry optimization

Tags: tables, macros

I am looking to get a better way of creating the following table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\makebox[\linewidth]{%
\rowcolors{2}{green!10}{white}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}p{3em}|*{12}{c}|p{3em}<{\centering}|}
\hline
Day of Month & \raisebox{-1.5ex}{Jan.} & \raisebox{-1.5ex}{Feb.} & \raisebox{-1.5ex}{Mar.} & \raisebox{-1.5ex}{Apr.} & \raisebox{-1.5ex}{May} & \raisebox{-1.5ex}{June} & \raisebox{-1.5ex}{July} & \raisebox{-1.5ex}{Aug.} & \raisebox{-1.5ex}{Sept.} & \raisebox{-1.5ex}{Oct.} & \raisebox{-1.5ex}{Nov.} & \raisebox{-1.5ex}{Dec.} & Day of Month%
\\ \hline
1 & 1 & 32 & 60 & 91 & 121 & 152 & 182 & 213 & 244 & 274 & 305 & 335 & 1%
\\ %\hline
2 & 2 & 33 & 61 & 92 & 122 & 153 & 183 & 214 & 245 & 275 & 306 & 336 & 2  %
\\ %\hline
3 & 3 & 34 & 62 & 93 & 123 & 154 & 184 & 215 & 246 & 276 & 307 & 337 & 3 %
\\ %\hline
4 & 4 & 35 & 63 & 94 & 124 & 155 & 185 & 216 & 247 & 277 & 308 & 338 & 4 %
\\ %\hline
5 & 5 & 36 & 64 & 95 & 125 &156 &186 &217 &248 &278 & 309& 339& 5%
\\ \hline
6 & 6 & 37 & 65 & 96 & 126 &157 &187 &218 &249 &279 &310 &340 & 6%
\\ %\hline
7 & 7 & 38 & 66&97 &127 &158 &188 &219 &250 &280 &311 &341 &7 %
\\ %\hline
8 & 8 &39& 67&98 &128 &159 &189 &220 &251 &281 &312 &342 &8 %
\\ %\hline
9 & 9 & 40&68 &99 &129 &160 &190 &221 &252 &282 &313 &343 &9 %
\\ %\hline
10 & 10 & 41&69 &100 &130 &161 &191 &222 &253 &283 &314 &344 &10 %
\\ \hline
11 & 11 & 42&70 &101 &131 &162 &192 &223 &254 &284 &315 &345 &11 %
\\ %\hline
12 & 12 & 43&71 &102 &132 &163 &193 & 224&255 &285 &316 &346 &12 %
\\ %\hline
13 & 13 &44&72 &103 & 133&164 &194 &225 &256 & 286&317 &347 &13 %
\\ %\hline
14 &14 & 45&73 &104 &134 &165 &195 &226 &257 & 287&318 &348 &14 %
\\ %\hline
15 & 15 &46&74 &105 & 135&166 &196 &227 &258 &288 &319 &349 &15 %
\\ \hline
16 & 16 & 47&75 &106 &136 &167 &197 &228 &259 &289 &320 &350 &16 %
\\ %\hline
17 & 17 &48& 76&107 & 137&168 &198 &229 &260 & 290& 321& 351& 17%
\\ %\hline
18 & 18 & 49& 77&108 & 138&169 &199 &230 &261 & 291& 322& 352& 18%
\\ %\hline
19 & 19 & 50& 78&109 & 139&170 &200 &231 &262 & 292& 323& 353& 19%
\\ %\hline
20 & 20 & 51& 79& 110& 140&171 &201 &232 &263 &293 &324 &354 &20 %
\\ \hline
21 & 21 &52& 80& 111& 141&172 &202 &233 &264 &294 & 325&355 & 21%
\\ %\hline
22 &22 & 53& 81& 112& 142& 173&203 &234 &265 & 295& 326& 356& 22%
\\ %\hline
23 &23 & 54& 82& 113& 143& 174&204 &235 &266 & 296& 327& 357& 23%
\\ %\hline
24 &24 & 55& 83& 114& 144& 175&205 &236 &267 & 297& 328& 358& 24%
\\ %\hline
25 &25 & 56& 84& 115& 145& 176&206 &237 &268 & 298& 329& 359& 25%
\\ \hline
26 &26 & 57& 85& 116& 146& 177&207 &238 &269 &299 & 330& 360& 26%
\\ %\hline
27 &27 & 58& 86& 117& 147& 178&208 &239 &270 &300 &331 &361 & 27%
\\ %\hline
28 &28 & 59& 87& 118& 148& 179&209 &240 &271 &301 &332 & 362& 28%
\\ %\hline
29 &29 & \ldots &88 &119 &149 &180 &210 &241 &272 &302 &333 & 363& 29%
\\ %\hline
30 &30 & \ldots &89 &120 &150 &181 &211 &242 &273 &303 &334 & 364& 30%
\\ %\hline
31 &31 & \ldots &90 & \ldots & 151 &\ldots &212 &243 &\ldots &304 &\ldots & 365&31 %
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

With better I mean more mathematical or algorithmic. I know, I know, I know.... its tedious as you can see, but at the time I had no time to rethink a different way of doing it.

Comment: not much more you could do is there? You could obviously automate the counting in the first and last column but that's only a small part of the table, the rest of it is not algorithmic but just a table of measured data isn't it? Or does your real data increase by one each row in the same way? `p{3em}<{\centering}` is a mightily devious trick, not seen that before:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I thought so. But i guess your expertise or someone elses will do the trick. Just need some inspiration to see if it can be done or not.

Comment: If your actual data just increases by one in each column, you could of course compress the whole table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this perhaps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\makebox[\linewidth]{%
\rowcolors{2}{green!10}{white}
\count7=1


\def\myrow{%
\the\count7 & 0 & 31 & 59 & 90 & 120 & 151 & 181 & 212 & 243 & 273 & 304 & 334 & \the\count7
\ifnum\count7<31
\global\advance\count7 1
\\\myrow
\fi}

\def\mon#1{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\raisebox{-1.5ex}{#1}}}

\begin{tabular}{!{\vrule width2pt}>{\centering}p{3em}!{\vrule width2pt}
*{12}{>{\def\ignorespaces{}\the\numexpr\count7+}c<\relax}|
>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3em}!{\vrule width2pt}}
\hline
\noalign{\vskip2pt}
Day of Month &
\mon{Jan.}&
\mon{Feb.}&
\mon{Mar.}&
\mon{Apr.}&
\mon{May}&
\mon{June}&
\mon{July}&
\mon{Aug.}&
\mon{Sept.}&
\mon{Oct.}&
\mon{Nov.}&
\mon{Dec.}&
Day of Month%
\\
\hline
\myrow
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the `\noalign{\vskip2pt}` necessary? IMHO looks better without it. Never seen the `!` in the tabular specifer. What does it actually do?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides usual viewer/zoom specific issues with coloured rows the hline was vanishing behind the white panel (same issue why I used !\vrule to drop in a wider vertical rule) `!` is an array package addition like `@` but does not remove the default tabcolsep space so `|` is the same as `!{\vline}`